# How can I compile SM 3.0 effects in D3D11 in SlimDX?

Tags: directx, directx11, directx9, slimdx

```
var bytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("shaders\\testShader.fx", "fx_5_0", ShaderFlags.None, SlimDX.D3DCompiler.EffectFlags.None, null, null, out str);
var effect = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.Effect(gpu.Device, bytecode);
```

This works fine but if I try to use another shader model like 4.0 or 3.0 it throws an error on the new effect creation:

```
E_FAIL: An undetermined error occurred (-2147467259)
```

How do I compile older shaders?  And I've read about device context but I can't find any information on how to use them to maintain DX9 compatibility.

Comment: So you're saying "fx_4_0" or "fx_3_0" doesn't work?  Does it work if in the effect file you specify vs_3_0 / ps_3_0 in the compile-expressions in the techniques?

Comment: Please expand.  The error is from `SlimDX.Direct3D11.Effect`?  What is the error output of `CompileFromFile` (the last arg there, I think).  What profiles does your fx file use?  What exact shader profile string are you putting in place of `"fx_5_0"` ?

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch there is no error output, str is just "", the new Effect instance causes the error.  I've tried using fx_4_0 and fx_3_0. NathanReed yeah I made sure to change the vertex and pixel declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"fx_5_0" refers to the *effect* file version, not the shader profile. Basically it's just telling the HLSL / effect compiler which version of syntax to allow.

You actually control which shader profiles are used when you use the CompileShader function inside your techniques in the effect, like so:

```
technique11 RenderSceneWithTexture1Light
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0_level_9_3, RenderSceneVS( 1, true, true ) ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0_level_9_3, RenderScenePS( true ) ) );
    }
}
```

That extra "_level_9_3" at the end specifies that you're making use of the 10level9 functionality. You can see what each feature level supports [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Unfortunately, there is no feature level that corresponds to SM 3.0 hardware. Your options are to stick with SM 2.x support in feature level 9_3 or to jump up to full D3D10-era SM 4.0.